# NSURLSession GET requests fail with 403 over HTTPS only - except when proxied

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am troubleshooting an app that is receiving a 403 response to certain NSURLSession GET requests. The request uses a custom header to carry an auth token.

The problem is that when I use Proxyman to view the request, it succeeds every time. The raw request including the auth header also succeeds via Postman and curl. It is only when made via the non-proxied app that it fails.

The source code itself suggests a 403 should be treated as "User Credential Failed", and the server log implies that a partial set of credentials may be included in the non-proxied request (a username is present), whereas they are missing from the proxied one.

I've seen suggestions that an ephemeral session config should be used with cookies and credential stores disabled, but no variation to the config has made any difference so far.

Here's the session setup code:

```
        
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral;
        
        sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(timeout);
        sessionConfig.urlCache = nil;
        sessionConfig.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadRevalidatingCacheData;
        
        sessionConfig.httpCookieStorage = .none
        sessionConfig.httpCookieAcceptPolicy = .never
        sessionConfig.httpShouldSetCookies = false
        sessionConfig.urlCredentialStorage = .none
        
        var headers: [AnyHashable: Any] = [AnyHashable: Any]();
        
        if let token = UserPreferences.getToken()
        {
            headers[HeaderTypes.Token.description] = token;
        }
        
        if let apiKey = self.apiKey
        {
            headers[HeaderTypes.API.description] = apiKey;
        }
        
        sessionConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = headers;
        
        self.session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig);
    }
```

Is there anything else I should be checking for?

Since the original post, we have tried/identified the following:

1. Most calls from the iOS app appear to work. It’s only those to a specific end point that fail.
2. Calls to that endpoint use an NSURLSession rather than an NSURLConnection. This is the main difference that we can see.
3. We’ve tested calls to the server using Curl and Postman, supplying an appropriate auth token, and these always succeed regardless of using HTTP or HTTPS.
4. Calls to the end point from the iOS app succeed when using HTTP.
5. Calls to the end point from the iOS app fail with a 403 when using HTTPS. The app’s previous programmers interpret a 403 as “Failed Credentials”
6. When we run the app through a proxy, which supplies its own HTTPS certificate, calls to the end point from the iOS app succeed using HTTPS.
7. We can see that when using HTTPS, an authentication challenge is raised in the app, giving it the chance to interrogate the validity of the HTTPS certificate. When we catch this and approve the validity, the server still returns a 403.
8. We’ve run diagnostics on calls to the server to check they pass Apple’s App Transport Security (ATS) requirements and they all pass.
9. We’ve tried multiple different settings for ATS, with no apparent difference in behaviour
10. We’ve tried forcing the TLS version up/down, with no apparent difference in behaviour
11. There is some anecdotal evidence that NSURLSession may pass cookies from previous requests to the server even when using token auth. Suggestions to bypass this include configuring the session to use an ephemeral configuration. No variations here made any difference.
12. The server logs indicate that each time the server returns a 403, it is aware of the specific user making the call, as the user name is populated in the logs. Successful calls do not have the user name recorded. This may corroborate the anecdotal evidence from point 11 but attempts to detect and remove the use of cookies were unsuccessful (ie we can’t see for sure if the app is sending cookies or not, and the code is set up to assume that it isn't).
13. Specific inclusion of user credentials (ie those used to log in) as well as the auth token in all calls has no effect either way.

Our current thinking is that some odd combination of the HTTPS set-up and the app's potential misuse of cookies under certain circumstances is causing the server to forbid requests to the end point (we have no direct access to the server, its configuration or code).

Comment: Info: when you get a [403 (forbidden)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), STL has been setup successfully. So, the issue is not related to TLS. Despite, you should check your [ATS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections) settings in your plist file. Also get a glimpse how the request is composed and sent over the wire Especially _check the encoding of the credentials_. Log the URLRequest, or/and use a tool like Charles Proxy, Fiddler, burb, mitmproxy, wireshark, etc.

Comment: Thanks @CouchDeveloper! Part of the problem is that when we interrogate the request with a proxy (we're using Proxyman), the request succeeds. TLS only came under the microscope because the request succeeds without it, but it's good to know it's not the negotiation causing the problem. Will check the credentials encoding aspect, thanks.

Comment: Well, that's true, but with the obvious caution that if you're overriding TLS validation in any way, you could inadvertently be breaking authentication if you don't use default handling for other protection spaces or whatever.